# MongoDB Projection Mechanism

Tags: mongodb

I wondered at projection mechanism in MongoDB.
do you know the required fields are projected from disk directly or from ram?
all entire document is fetched to ram and then projection happens or only required fields are fetched from disk in ram?

Comment: It's a database. Ideally **everything** happens in RAM. But things don't always work out ideally. If you are basically asking "whole document or just what was asked for?" Then it's much like asking "Whole collection or just what was asked for?" So it becomes more obvious it's **just what was asked for**. Beyond that this becomes a very broad subject.

Comment: I want to know that if I use projection in my query on a collection, what is happening in low level. imagine there is a document with 15 fields in a 
 collection. if I specify to return only 10 of the fields, how the projection happens? in ram or in the disk? does the MongoDB fetch the 10 specified fields from the disk or fetch all 15 fields into ram and the returns those specified 10? @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB keeps all of the most recently used data in RAM.If your working data set fits in RAM, MongoDB serves all queries from memory, else it will hit the disk to access the data.

Now how can you check if the data is retrieved from RAM or disk?

1. Observe the yields field on any query while using $explain operator. This will tell you how many times the reader yielded its lock because data was not in the RAM.
2. Programs like mongostat can tell you about what page faults (when data needs to be paged into RAM from disk) are happening on your mongoDB instance.